# Showing Layer error: Classifier training failed: 'Only one class.'

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to perform RandomForest Classification in my study area,using LANDSAT 7 TIER-2 SR. But I have been getting this error,

```
classification: Layer error: Classifier training failed: 'Only one class.'.
```

Although I have kept different values for my featurecollections, it shows this above error. Where am I going wrong?

Please find my [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/d079b2f807aed75130397bef2cfe3c70) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `Map.addLayer(image);`, I determined that your selected image only overlaps one of the classes, `other`. Therefore, all of the sample points have that class, resulting in the error.

[image: Picture of non-overlap]

In order to get coverage for all of your training regions, you should not pick just the `.first()` image matching your query, but a mosaic of many images. I modified your image expression to this:

```rust
var image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterBounds(thane)
    .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31')
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER', false)
    .select(bands)
    .mosaic();
```

Instead of sorting by cloud cover ascending and taking the first image, I sort descending (the `false` second argument) and make a `mosaic()`, so that each pixel is the least cloudy image's pixel (within that date range).

(You might wish to choose some other blending such as taking the median value; I am not a remote sensing or machine learning expert and cannot tell you the best option for this application.)

This lets the script run successfully and it produces this classification:

[image: Classification results]

https://code.earthengine.google.com/bfb80e22596fcbe67f47b7524324c5d1

Comment: Thankyou for your detailed solution. This helped me understand the use of ```.mosiac()```